# Problem with running Django with nginx and uwsgi in Ubuntu

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, psycopg2, uwsgi

I'm trying to install a new server, and I can't run Django with nginx and uwsgi. I receive an error "502 Bad Gateway" and there are messages on the error log which I don't understand:

```
2019/07/20 10:50:44 [error] 2590#2590: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 79.183.208.33, server: *.speedy.net.3.speedy-technologies.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/run/uwsgi/app/speedy_net/socket:", host: "3.speedy-technologies.com"
```

I have 4 websites and here is the main (default) configuration file:

```
server {
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name *.speedy.net.3.speedy-technologies.com speedy.net.3.speedy-technologies.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/speedy-net.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/speedy-net.error.log;

    client_max_body_size 50M;

    root  /home/ubuntu/speedy-net/speedy/net/static_serve/root;
    try_files $uri @uwsgi;

    location @uwsgi {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/app/speedy_net/socket;
    }

    location /admin/ {
        auth_basic "admin site";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd_admin;
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi/app/speedy_net/socket;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/speedy-net/speedy/net/static_serve;
        access_log off;
        # expires max;
        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1100;
        gzip_buffers 4 32k;
        gzip_types text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/x-component application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/xml  application/rss+xml font/truetype application/x-font-ttf font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
    }
}
```

And:

```
[uwsgi]
project = net

chdir = /home/ubuntu/speedy-net
home = %(chdir)/env
module = speedy.%(project).wsgi:application

plugins = python3
master = true
processes = 4

chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true

uid = ubuntu
gid = ubuntu

touch-reload = /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_%(project)/reload
```

I tried to test with `sudo nginx -t` but I received a message that my configuration is OK. What is the problem?

**Edit:**

The old server (which is working):

```
$ find /run/uwsgi/ -ls
  489      0 drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root           60 Jul 20 08:41 /run/uwsgi/
  490      0 drwxr-xr-x   6 root     root          120 Jul 20 08:41 /run/uwsgi/app
  500      0 drwxr-xr-x   2 ubuntu   ubuntu        100 Jul 20 08:42 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_net
  523      0 -rw-rw-r--   1 ubuntu   ubuntu          0 Jul 20 08:43 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_net/reload
  501      0 srw-rw-rw-   1 ubuntu   ubuntu          0 Jul 20 08:41 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_net/socket
  457      4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root            5 Jul 20 08:41 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_net/pid
  498      0 drwxr-xr-x   2 ubuntu   ubuntu        100 Jul 20 08:42 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_match
  524      0 -rw-rw-r--   1 ubuntu   ubuntu          0 Jul 20 08:43 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_match/reload
  499      0 srw-rw-rw-   1 ubuntu   ubuntu          0 Jul 20 08:41 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_match/socket
  413      4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root            5 Jul 20 08:41 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_match/pid
  495      0 drwxr-xr-x   2 ubuntu   ubuntu        100 Jul 20 08:43 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_mail
  528      0 -rw-rw-r--   1 ubuntu   ubuntu          0 Jul 20 08:43 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_mail/reload
  497      0 srw-rw-rw-   1 ubuntu   ubuntu          0 Jul 20 08:41 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_mail/socket
  496      4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root            5 Jul 20 08:41 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_mail/pid
  491      0 drwxr-xr-x   2 ubuntu   ubuntu        100 Jul 20 08:42 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_composer
  527      0 -rw-rw-r--   1 ubuntu   ubuntu          0 Jul 20 08:43 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_composer/reload
  494      0 srw-rw-rw-   1 ubuntu   ubuntu          0 Jul 20 08:41 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_composer/socket
  493      4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root            5 Jul 20 08:41 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_composer/pid
```

The new server:

```
$ find /run/uwsgi/ -ls
  554      0 drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root           60 Jul 20 10:15 /run/uwsgi/
  555      0 drwxr-xr-x   6 root     root          120 Jul 20 11:14 /run/uwsgi/app
  573      0 drwxr-xr-x   2 ubuntu   ubuntu         80 Jul 20 11:14 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_net
  598      0 srw-rw-rw-   1 ubuntu   ubuntu          0 Jul 20 11:14 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_net/socket
  584      4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root            5 Jul 20 11:14 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_net/pid
  568      0 drwxr-xr-x   2 ubuntu   ubuntu         80 Jul 20 11:14 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_match
  572      0 srw-rw-rw-   1 ubuntu   ubuntu          0 Jul 20 11:14 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_match/socket
  569      4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root            5 Jul 20 11:14 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_match/pid
  565      0 drwxr-xr-x   2 ubuntu   ubuntu         80 Jul 20 11:14 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_mail
  567      0 srw-rw-rw-   1 ubuntu   ubuntu          0 Jul 20 11:14 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_mail/socket
  566      4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root            5 Jul 20 11:14 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_mail/pid
  499      0 drwxr-xr-x   2 ubuntu   ubuntu         80 Jul 20 11:14 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_composer
  564      0 srw-rw-rw-   1 ubuntu   ubuntu          0 Jul 20 11:14 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_composer/socket
  561      4 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root            5 Jul 20 11:14 /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_composer/pid
```

The old server is `Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS`, and the new server is `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS`.

I checked `/var/log/uwsgi/app/speedy_net.log` and it contains lots of lines. Here are the last 5 lines:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x21c393) [0x7fe09b2ac393]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5170) [0x7fe09b277b70]
*** end of backtrace ***
Sun Aug 11 11:24:35 2019 - DAMN ! worker 2 (pid: 6874) died :( trying respawn ...
Sun Aug 11 11:24:35 2019 - Respawned uWSGI worker 2 (new pid: 6906)
```

The last 7 lines are now:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyCFunction_FastCallDict+0x13a) [0x7f4d7c245e2a]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x21c393) [0x7f4d7c31a393]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5170) [0x7f4d7c2e5b70]
*** end of backtrace ***
Sun Aug 11 11:37:17 2019 - DAMN ! worker 2 (pid: 7915) died :( trying respawn ...
Sun Aug 11 11:37:17 2019 - Respawned uWSGI worker 2 (new pid: 7944)
Sun Aug 11 11:37:17 2019 - epoll_ctl(): File exists [core/event.c line 524]
```

And:

```
Sun Aug 11 11:42:56 2019 - epoll_ctl(): File exists [core/event.c line 524]
Sun Aug 11 11:42:56 2019 - epoll_ctl(): File exists [core/event.c line 524]
Sun Aug 11 11:42:56 2019 - !!! uWSGI process 8118 got Segmentation Fault !!!
Sun Aug 11 11:42:56 2019 - *** backtrace of 8118 ***
/usr/bin/uwsgi(uwsgi_backtrace+0x2a) [0x563d84f5098a]
/usr/bin/uwsgi(uwsgi_segfault+0x23) [0x563d84f50d73]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3ef20) [0x7f4d7ff98f20]
/home/ubuntu/speedy-net/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/./libssl-c0c2ede4.so.1.0.2q(ssl3_cleanup_key_block+0xb) [0x7f4d773d4cab]
/home/ubuntu/speedy-net/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/./libssl-c0c2ede4.so.1.0.2q(ssl3_clear+0x16) [0x7f4d773d25a6]
/home/ubuntu/speedy-net/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/./libssl-c0c2ede4.so.1.0.2q(tls1_clear+0x9) [0x7f4d773de219]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1(SSL_new+0x3f2) [0x7f4d80c11a22]
/home/ubuntu/speedy-net/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-bd31fe2b.so.5.11(+0x23969) [0x7f4d77669969]
/home/ubuntu/speedy-net/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-bd31fe2b.so.5.11(+0x24fc5) [0x7f4d7766afc5]
/home/ubuntu/speedy-net/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-bd31fe2b.so.5.11(PQconnectPoll+0xb78) [0x7f4d77654ba8]
/home/ubuntu/speedy-net/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-bd31fe2b.so.5.11(+0xfa28) [0x7f4d77655a28]
/home/ubuntu/speedy-net/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-bd31fe2b.so.5.11(PQconnectdb+0x1f) [0x7f4d7765841f]
/home/ubuntu/speedy-net/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x12b01) [0x7f4d778a9b01]
/home/ubuntu/speedy-net/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x1388f) [0x7f4d778aa88f]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x122342) [0x7f4d7c220342]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyObject_FastCallDict+0x89) [0x7f4d7c333e19]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyObject_CallFunction_SizeT+0x124) [0x7f4d7c334ce4]
/home/ubuntu/speedy-net/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0xc258) [0x7f4d778a3258]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(PyCFunction_Call+0x96) [0x7f4d7c2460a6]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x7a50) [0x7f4d7c2e8450]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x21bbab) [0x7f4d7c319bab]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x3e) [0x7f4d7c31a67e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x1beeb3) [0x7f4d7c2bceb3]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x48) [0x7f4d7c334b08]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x4001) [0x7f4d7c2e4a01]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x21a953) [0x7f4d7c318953]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x21c472) [0x7f4d7c31a472]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5170) [0x7f4d7c2e5b70]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x21a953) [0x7f4d7c318953]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x21c472) [0x7f4d7c31a472]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5170) [0x7f4d7c2e5b70]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x21a953) [0x7f4d7c318953]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x21c472) [0x7f4d7c31a472]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5170) [0x7f4d7c2e5b70]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x21bbab) [0x7f4d7c319bab]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x21c29e) [0x7f4d7c31a29e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5170) [0x7f4d7c2e5b70]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x21a953) [0x7f4d7c318953]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x21c472) [0x7f4d7c31a472]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5170) [0x7f4d7c2e5b70]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x21bbab) [0x7f4d7c319bab]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x21c29e) [0x7f4d7c31a29e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x3ea5) [0x7f4d7c2e48a5]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x1c85ec) [0x7f4d7c2c65ec]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x1bc496) [0x7f4d7c2ba496]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x1bc970) [0x7f4d7c2ba970]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x122342) [0x7f4d7c220342]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyObject_FastCallDict+0x89) [0x7f4d7c333e19]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x21c058) [0x7f4d7c31a058]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5170) [0x7f4d7c2e5b70]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x21a953) [0x7f4d7c318953]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x21c472) [0x7f4d7c31a472]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5170) [0x7f4d7c2e5b70]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x21a953) [0x7f4d7c318953]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyFunction_FastCallDict+0x2c3) [0x7f4d7c319fb3]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyObject_FastCallDict+0x131) [0x7f4d7c333ec1]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyObject_Call_Prepend+0xcd) [0x7f4d7c334a9d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyObject_FastCallDict+0x89) [0x7f4d7c333e19]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x270821) [0x7f4d7c36e821]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0xb8ef5) [0x7f4d7c1b6ef5]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x1ec989) [0x7f4d7c2ea989]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyCFunction_FastCallDict+0x13a) [0x7f4d7c245e2a]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x21c393) [0x7f4d7c31a393]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5170) [0x7f4d7c2e5b70]
*** end of backtrace ***
Sun Aug 11 11:42:57 2019 - DAMN ! worker 2 (pid: 8118) died :( trying respawn ...
Sun Aug 11 11:42:57 2019 - Respawned uWSGI worker 2 (new pid: 8124)
Sun Aug 11 11:42:57 2019 - epoll_ctl(): File exists [core/event.c line 524]
```

The connection to the database (PostgreSQL) works from the command line, for example this code works fine:

```
import django

django.setup()

from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

for site in Site.objects.all().order_by('pk'):
    print(site.id, site.domain)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [uwsgi segmentation fault when serving a django application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498240/uwsgi-segmentation-fault-when-serving-a-django-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually it was https://stackoverflow.com/a/54253374/57952. I had to run the following 2 commands:

```
/home/ubuntu/speedy-net/env/bin/pip uninstall psycopg2
/home/ubuntu/speedy-net/env/bin/pip install --no-binary :all: psycopg2==2.7.7
```

And then the server started to work.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues that may be there, you need to debug and see what is wrong

**1. ALLOWED_HOSTS is not set**

If you the django config doesn't have `ALLOWED_HOSTS` set then this may create an error

**2. nginx config is missing some directives**

Some people were able to fix their issues using below

```
sendfile        on;
client_max_body_size 20M;
keepalive_timeout  0;
large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;
```

See if adding that to your route helps

**3. Django app is crashing with some unhandled exception**

This requires you to look at the `uwsgi` logs. You can do that by running the `uwsgi` process in one terminal instead of a as a service or set the log path in `uwsgi.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
logto=/var/log/uwsgi.log
log-ioerror=1
```

And then look at logs to see what is causing the crash

**4. Your request is taking time and getting timed out**

In this case you need to increase the `uwsgi` timeout. This you can do by adding below to `uwsgi.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
harakiri = 120
```

and below to the nginx config

```
uwsgi_read_timeout 120s;
uwsgi_send_timeout 120s;
```

5. **uwsgi crash with segmentation fault**

If you look at the logs you shared

```
/usr/bin/uwsgi(uwsgi_segfault+0x23) [0x563d84f50d73]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3ef20) [0x7f4d7ff98f20]
/home/ubuntu/speedy-net/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/./libssl-c0c2ede4.so.1.0.2q(ssl3_cleanup_key_block+0xb) [0x7f4d773d4cab]
/home/ubuntu/speedy-net/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/./libssl-c0c2ede4.so.1.0.2q(ssl3_clear+0x16) [0x7f4d773d25a6]
/home/ubuntu/speedy-net/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/./libssl-c0c2ede4.so.1.0.2q(tls1_clear+0x9) [0x7f4d773de219]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1(SSL_new+0x3f2) [0x7f4d80c11a22]
/home/ubuntu/speedy-net/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-bd31fe2b.so.5.11(+0x23969) [0x7f4d77669969]
/home/ubuntu/speedy-net/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-bd31fe2b.so.5.11(+0x24fc5) [0x7f4d7766afc5]
/home/ubuntu/speedy-net/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-bd31fe2b.so.5.11(PQconnectPoll+0xb78) [0x7f4d77654ba8]
/home/ubuntu/speedy-net/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-bd31fe2b.so.5.11(+0xfa28) [0x7f4d77655a28]
/home/ubuntu/speedy-net/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libpq-bd31fe2b.so.5.11(PQconnectdb+0x1f) [0x7f4d7765841f]
/home/ubuntu/speedy-net/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x12b01) [0x7f4d778a9b01]
/home/ubuntu/speedy-net/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x1388f) [0x7f4d778aa88f]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0(+0x122342) [0x7f4d7c220342]
```

These show that the crash happens because of the Postgres DB connection and ssl. Now there are lot of threads which talk about different solutions that can help you resolve the issue

[uwsgi segmentation fault when serving a django application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498240/uwsgi-segmentation-fault-when-serving-a-django-application)

[django app under uwsgi failing to start when using postgresql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848478/django-app-under-uwsgi-failing-to-start-when-using-postgresql-database)

[Error importing psycopg2._psycopg when using uWSGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34869633/error-importing-psycopg2-psycopg-when-using-uwsgi)

[uwsgi segmentation fault for one specific route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53496524/uwsgi-segmentation-fault-for-one-specific-route)

**References**

https://serverfault.com/questions/276462/nginx-uwsgi-gives-502-bad-gateway

["upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream" Django, Ubuntu, Nginx, Gunicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162420/upstream-prematurely-closed-connection-while-reading-response-header-from-upstr)

[uWSGI request timeout in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127601/uwsgi-request-timeout-in-python)

[upstream prematurely closed connection (uwsgi + nginx + django)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558242/upstream-prematurely-closed-connection-uwsgi-nginx-django)

[nginx uwsgi websockets 502 Bad Gateway upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470448/nginx-uwsgi-websockets-502-bad-gateway-upstream-prematurely-closed-connection-wh)

[uwsgi + nginx + flask: upstream prematurely closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396248/uwsgi-nginx-flask-upstream-prematurely-closed)

[nginx, uwsgi, DJango, 502 when DEBUG=False, "upstream prematurely closed connection"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464235/nginx-uwsgi-django-502-when-debug-false-upstream-prematurely-closed-connect)

Comment: `logto=/var/log/uwsgi.log` and `log-ioerror=1` on `/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/speedy_net.ini` don't change anything after I restarted uwsgi with `sudo service uwsgi restart`. I still see log lines on `/var/log/uwsgi/app/speedy_net.log`. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Your logs indicate the worker is crashing, see if you can get the worker logs? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-check-error-logs-for-flask-uwsgi-nginx-app

Comment: Cool this should help, see the thread https://stackoverflow.com/q/53498240/2830850

Comment: @Uri, please check the update answer, now your problem should be solved

Comment: The connection to the database (PostgreSQL) works from the command line. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Yes, that will work. The issue is not DB, it is the uwsgi is compiled with SSL vX and Postgres DB driver with SSL vY. So when you use both of them together it causes the crash

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a socket directive to the uwsgi config file.

```
socket = /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_%(project)/socket
```

You have to tell uwsgi where to find the socket. Maybe on the old server the socket path is passed as a command line flag?

Both the nginx user and the uswgi user should have `rw` permissions to the socket itself and `rx` permissions to every parent directory. You can check that both users can write to the socket by running `touch` as the corresponding users.

```
sudo --user=nginx touch /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_net/socket
sudo --user=uwsgi touch /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_net/socket
```

If any of these fail, there's a permission problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked and both the old server (which is working) and the new server don't have users `nginx` and `uwsgi`. Are you sure these users are necessary?

Comment: Adding `socket = /run/uwsgi/app/speedy_%(project)/socket` to the uwsgi config file doesn't work, and it's not existing in the old server's uwsgi config files.

Comment: The usernames are just examples. It looks like uwsgi is running under the user `ubuntu` on your system.

Comment: If the socket name is not configured in the uwsgi ini file, it must be somewhere else. You should look for some other config on the old server. If you use supervisord or systemd or something else to mange uwsgi, look at the corresponding service configuration there. Look for something like `uwsgi --socket=/run/uwsgi/app/speedy_net/socket`

Comment: I think uwsgi is running as user `ubuntu` and nginx is running as `root`, but I'm not sure. Do you know how I can check it?

Comment: try `ps -ef | grep nginx`